# Postgis and Postgresql: type error "st_point" does not exist

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, postgis, postgresql-9.4

I followed https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostGIS21UbuntuPGSQL93Apt guide to setup a PostGIS on Ubuntu 14.04 and despite the fact that process was very smooth by itself, the result is not so rewarding.

Even while I was able to create an extension in the database with `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;`, still  query `ALTER TABLE "realties" ADD "coordinates" ST_Point;` throws an `ERROR: type error "st_point" does not exist`.

Server version is 9.4.5 (package postgresql-9.4-postgis-2.1)

Can anyone possibly know how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PostGis only creates a generic type `geometry`. Objects of type `geometry` can be points, polygons and so on.

[ST_Point](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Point.html) is not a type but a function which returns a geometry of type Point.

Thus the correct syntax is:

```
ALTER TABLE "realties" ADD "coordinates" geometry(Point);
```

If you know which [SRID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRID) you will use, is good practice to specify the srid as well, in example:

```
ALTER TABLE "realties" ADD "coordinates" geometry(Point, 4326);
```

If you are not sure, what kinds of geometries you will store, do not specify nothing:

```
ALTER TABLE "realties" ADD "coordinates" geometry;
```

PS: Postgis also offer a `geography` type, which is similar to `geometry`. For more infos: http://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#PostGIS_Geography